# Assigning a value for view asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm just firing up node and trying to get used to the asynchronous behavior, but I'm having an issue assigning a value when it comes to rendering the view.  The code base is very simple:

in a custom module:

```
var fs = require('fs')

exports.drawCard = function (color, callback) {
  fs.readFile(color, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) { callback(err); return }
    var card = sample(data.split(/\n/))
    callback(err, card)
  })
}
```

in the routes file:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  var deck = require('./../deck.js')

  console.log(newCard)
  res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Bits AH',
    //This is what I would like
    card: deck.drawCard("green")
  })
};
```

I know that isn't how you assign the variable, but it's the general idea I'm shooting for. I can't figure out the code/node way to just do this simple assignment

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're going for?

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  var deck = require('./../deck'); // No .js required

  deck.drawCard(function(err, card) {
    if(err) {
      res.render('error');
      return;
    }

    res.render('index', { 
      title: 'Bits AH',
      card: card
    });
  });
};
```

You're wrapping the res.render call inside the callback to the drawCard function because you can't return until after the function is completed. It's possible however to load those files when the module is initialized, and then you can convert your drawCard function to be synchronous and then you could use it like you have in your example.